# Basic probability questions about dice rolls

Tags: probability

This is from the Probability for Dummies text: Suppose you roll two dice, one red die and one green die. Let event $A$ represent getting an odd number when you roll a red die and let event $B$ represent getting an even number when you roll a green die. 
Then all possible cases are:

[image]

Why is the last one $\cup$? Is the last one a mistake? shouldn't it be $\cap$ instead of $\cup$? shouldn't all of these be $\cap$ since we're talking about *both* dice?

thanks

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an error. You are correct.